# How to show only one validation at a time in angular 6 form control validators

Tags: validation, angular-material, angular6, form-control

I am using form control to apply validation in material angular 6 application.

Below is the code of validator :-

```
paymentOffBankName: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
Validators.required,
Validators.maxLength(this.responseMap.get('ev_payment_t.bank_name').values.maxSize),
Validators.minLength(this.responseMap.get('ev_payment_t.bank_name').values.minSize),
Validators.pattern(this.responseMap.get('ev_payment_t.bank_name').values.validationExp)

])),
```

I have one method to display the message related validator :-

```
paymentOffBankName': [
{ type: 'required', message: 'Required') },
{ type: 'pattern', message: 'Invalid Name' },
{ type: 'minlength', message: 'Requires atleast 3 letters'
},

],
```

Here is my html which shows the error :-

```
<mat-form-field fxFlex="{{responseMap.get('ev_payment_t.bank_name').values.maxSize}}">
<input required matInput placeholder="{{responseMap.get('ev_payment_t.bank_name').values.label}}"
formControlName="paymentOffBankName" maxlength="{{responseMap.get('ev_payment_t.bank_name').values.maxSize}}">
<mat-error *ngFor="let validation of validationMessages.paymentOffBankName">
<mat-error class="error-message" *ngIf="offlinePaymentService.OfflinePayment_form.get('paymentOffBankName').hasError(validation.type) && (offlinePaymentService.OfflinePayment_form.get('paymentOffBankName').dirty || offlinePaymentService.OfflinePayment_form.get('paymentOffBankName').touched)">{{validation.message}}</mat-error>
</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

My Problem is,  If I put invalid name with 2 letters, then it shows two validation messages.

Expectation: It should show only one message, I will put one common message like 'Required, MinLengh-3, Alpha Numeric only'

Answer (score 0):

To show only one validation message at a time, try to use `messageKey` in which you can pass `composeMessageKey` which contains all the validation messages of the field.

Declare the `composeMessageKey` in app component

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(){
    ReactiveFormConfig.set({"validationMessage":{
      "composeMessageKey":"please enter valid input"
      }});
  }
}
```

and in component ts:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.userFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      paymentOffBankName:['', RxwebValidators.compose(
        {validators:[
          RxwebValidators.alpha(),
          RxwebValidators.maxLength({value:3}),
          RxwebValidators.minLength({value:4}),

          ],messageKey:"composeMessageKey",
        })         
      ]
  });

}
```

For that i have used validators of @rxweb validators(RxwebValidators) and passed the MessageKey

Html :

```
<div>
  <form  [formGroup]="userFormGroup">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Payment Off BankName</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="paymentOffBankName" class="form-control"  />
    </div>
      <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="userFormGroup.controls.paymentOffBankName.errors">{{userFormGroup.controls.paymentOffBankName.errors.composeMessageKey?.message}}<br/></small>    
    <button [disabled]="!userFormGroup.valid" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is the stackblitz example : [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxweb-compose-validator-djghnm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcompose-add.component.ts)